# É possível usar servidor C# + Client Delphi?

Tags: c#, delphi, web-service

O C# possui um *framework* ORM muito bom, isso ajudaria muito na hora de criar um servidor *webservice* entre o cliente e o banco de dados.

Já o Delphi possui muitos componentes que ajudam na hora de desenvolver uma aplicação de automação comercial.

Existe algum impedimento em utilizar ambos juntos? Objetivamente, seria correto usá-los juntos?

Comment: Não tem nada que o Delphi tenha para aplicativos Windows que o C# não tenha igual ou similar melhorado. Vá de C#.

Comment: Como seriam esses componentes para uma aplicação de automação comercial que o Delphi seria melhor que o C#?

Comment: ACBr provavelmente, mas acho q eles possuem uma dll para ser consumida pelo C#

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cada caso é um caso.

É possível usar ambos e fazê-los comunicar através de *webservices* ou algo semelhante. A intenção do *webservice*, que nem sempre é a melhor solução, é justamente tecnologias poderem se comunicar sem entender os detalhes da comunicação e funcionamento da outra parte. Ele é usado para padronizar o acesso a dados de uma aplicação por outra aplicação.

Claro que eu tentaria fazer uma aplicação homogênea sempre que possível, e me parece que este caso não é só possível, é desejável.

Duvido que valha o trabalho de criar *webservices* para aproveitar um componente que te ajude em alguma tarefa. Algo que provavelmente pode ser feito de forma fácil também em C# e que deve ter algo pronto para usar com esta linguagem. Mas se precisa dos *webservices* por outros motivos, aí já começa ter vantagens.

Ou seja, entenda porque você está escolhendo cada um, mas não separe a aplicação em duas só porque uma linguagem possui melhores componentes para uma coisa e a outra possui melhores componentes para outra.

Comment: Ótima resposta bigown. A ideia do webservice é para que futuramente seja fácil disponibilizar módulos web e mobile.